# Was Nolan Sorrento supposed to look like a nemesis from a 1980's movie?

Tags: character, casting, ready-player-one

In *Ready Player One*, the actor Ben Mendelsohn plays Nolan Sorrento, an authority figure who is out of touch with what's important to the "gunters" who play in the Oasis.

[image]

I noticed that he bears a striking resemblance to the actor Paul Gleason, who played a similar out-of-touch authority figure in many popular movies from the 80's including *Trading Places*, *Die Hard*, and *The Breakfast Club*.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Was this similarity intentional, either on the part of Steven Spielberg or the casting director?

Comment: Is 'gunters' really the word they used? I won't even hint at looking up the word 'gunt' in case someone actually does, but it's really not one to be used in polite society :\

Comment: @Tetsujin Smart to be cautious! But yes, the word is "gunters", which is short for "egg hunters". (In the book, it's spelled the way I spelled it.)

Comment: unfortunate accident , then :\

Comment: He mostly reminded me of Ed Dillinger from Tron...very similar persona and appearance.  See here: https://tron.fandom.com/wiki/Ed_Dillinger

Comment: @binarymax Wow, right! I'd forgotten about that guy.

Comment: Considering the entire move is a smorgasbord of 80s references, I wouldn't be at all surprised if that's exactly what they did.  I don't have any sources, though.

Comment: @Steve-O I didn't find any sources either, but it does seem likely.

Comment: *End of line, Bender. I got you for two weeks on the game grid verses Asian Dawn.*